# use parent size as image attributes

Tags: jquery, css

While the following jQuery can determine the size of a div

```
<div>
  <script>
    var box = document.querySelector('div');
    // width and height in pixels, including padding and border
    // Corresponds to jQuery outerWidth(), outerHeight()
    var width = box.offsetWidth;
    var height = box.offsetHeight;
  </script>
  <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gpi/haley-phelps-433522.jpg' width='' height=''>
</div>
```

Assuming the image's aspect ratio is the same as the div, how can the width and height variables be invoked to set the child image's dimension

Comment: you mean do we have to set height and width of image, by fetching div height width?

Comment: Could you not just use CSS? `.container img { width: 100%; height: 100% }`. This obviously assumes the parent has its dimensions set too.

Comment: assuming they have the same aspect ratio, you just need to set width:100% on the image

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan @Pete this is working only under firefox.  the parent itself is subject to `transition` and `transform` which somehow negate the css setting.  So I would rather go one notch below and get the data outright to keep things simpler.

Comment: don't see how a transform would negate the css setting for width and height

Comment: The question is not clear. In your code, the div is already as high as the img, because elements with display:block adjust themselves to their content. So the offsetHeight you get is basically the height of the img, and there is nothing to solve! Now according to the comments, your real situation is different, so can you produce a [mcve] that actually reflects the problem you're having?

Comment: the code snippet at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51533112/chrome-browsers-scrolling-background-image  demonstrates where width: 100% is not handling the images aspect ration properly in Chrome, Opera, Safari (works as desired in Firefox)

Comment: Using a background image may work better for you, given what you describe, along with `background-size: cover`

Comment: @Pete  'somehow' is intended as an assumption.  What is clear from the code snippet is that there are competing instructions (could be the JS FAIK).  Thus, changing the problem to a simple image (with its layer) and getting computed with and height, simplifies matters.

Comment: nothing is clear in the above question, I have voted to close and moved on

Comment: @Pete sorry if it is not clear, but most comments have rushed on to find solutions which do not address the question.  All I asked is how can I invoke the variable generated from the jQuery variable to set the image width and height (not other approaches)...

Comment: `box.querySelector('img').style.width = width + 'px';` the px bit is if the offset width doesn't come back with px - don't think it does

Answer (score 1):

This way the image uses all the space from it's parent.

```html
<div style="width: 640px; height: 480px;">
  <img src='https://loremflickr.com/320/240' style="width: 100%">
</div>
```